# Linux USB problems on Ubuntu/Mint

Tags: memory, linux-mint, usb-3, fat32

After some updates (4.4.0 kernel, Linux Mint 18) I realized that older USB memory sticks are having troubles while new highspeed USB sticks, e.g. 32GB work well.

Using one of my older USB sticks (format: fat32) e.g. 2GB, 4GB are causing problems. During a copy process of files greater than 1GB, nemo hangs, the percentage remains at e.g. 85% and I cannot interrupt or stop it. If I kill the process, a  zombie process remains.

Strange thing is that copying had worked always best within Linux. Something has broken now and I guess the reason might be USB3.0 support. I have read a lot of bad comments about USB3.0.

Now copying has become a process which might work or not. This drives me crazy.
I have double checked the USB sticks and the problem definitely is software and not corrupted hardware.

Does anybody know the real reasons for?

```
[40700.770962] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[40701.205675] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1643
[40701.205683] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[40701.205688] usb 3-1: Product: DataTraveler G3
[40701.205692] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[40701.205696] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 001CC0EC34A2F091C7D61521
[40701.205997] usb 3-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 255 microframes
[40701.206009] usb 3-1: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 255 microframes
[40701.206350] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[40701.207996] scsi host7: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[40702.209910] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler G3  1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[40702.210762] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[40702.210805] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 7555528 512-byte logical blocks: (3.87 GB/3.60 GiB)
[40702.210947] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[40702.210953] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[40702.211113] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[40702.211119] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[40702.213402]  sdb: sdb1
[40702.215152] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[40697.439152] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[40700.770962] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[40701.205675] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1643
[40701.205683] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[40701.205688] usb 3-1: Product: DataTraveler G3
[40701.205692] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[40701.205696] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 001CC0EC34A2F091C7D61521
[40701.205997] usb 3-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 255 microframes
[40701.206009] usb 3-1: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 255 microframes
[40701.206350] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[40701.207996] scsi host7: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[40702.209910] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler G3  1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[40702.210762] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[40702.210805] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 7555528 512-byte logical blocks: (3.87 GB/3.60 GiB)
[40702.210947] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[40702.210953] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[40702.211113] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[40702.211119] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[40702.213402]  sdb: sdb1
[40702.215152] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: You are on 18.0, not 18.3? If so, you should really upgrade following the Mint blog posts for each revision's release notes (18.1, 18.2, 18.3) and update to the latest 4.10 kernel since 18.0 is no longer supported and 18.3 is LTS until 2021. That said, why not just rollback your kernel? To actually troubleshoot this, you would need to clear dmesg with `sudo dmesg -c` then connect a USB drive, perform an action that causes it to fail, stop the process and remove the drive, and post the output of `dmesg`

Comment: Don't have to clear dmesg, just watch for new messages when connecting, reading, writing to (& possibly disconnecting) the usb drives. And syslog usually has more messages/details too (often `/var/log/syslog` but it's customizable)

Comment: Thank you. I have posted the output of dmesg. The infobox for the copy process hangs again, saying copying file xxx to yyy, 1,5GB of 1,5GB, 0 seconds remaining (but does not finish). Next step I can do is to kill the process.